# Django Rest Framework: Non-model service

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been using django-rest-framework for creating services that work with the models. Now I need to create a service that receives some data, evaluates it and sends a notification email. It has been difficult to find such use case in django-rest-framework documentation and I think Function based views(at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views#function-based-views) would be the best approach but not sure if it is. There is very few documentation of it around. Which would be the best way to implement such service?

Comment: Just to clarify: your function will be receiving data from an external API? Will it be initiated by some sort of request by a user or more of an automated background task?

Comment: The function I want to publish as a service will be receiving data from an angularJS application and process it in order to send a notification.

Answer (score 0):

The default DRF `APIView` knows nothing about models, as `ViewSet` and `GenericViewSet`. 
The DRF function based views are only syntactic sugar on the default `APIView`.

The one you should use depends on your functionality, perhaps have a look at [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#api-reference) for clarity.

Comment: I have read about GenericViewSet and tested it, however, I wasn't able to have it running as it needs some extra implementation or inheritance like the mixins classes, which seem to be based on model mixins. I would appreciate if you could refer me to an example or reference for GenericViewSet use. Haven't been able to find much about that.

Comment: first starting point would be the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#genericviewset)

If you get stuck on this, please provide some code snippets of your current implementation, then we can perhaps help on this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will post the specific error I get when trying to use GenericViewSet.